# How to create an object for every row in a two-dimensional array of Strings

Tags: java, list, matrix

I have a matrix of objects that contains data in this form:

```
name A,2,name B
name C,3,name D
name E,4,name F
name G,5,name H
```

My code to process the data is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numColumn; j++) {
        Object o = matrix[i][j];
        String x = o.toString();
    }
}
```

In this way, `x` assumes these values in turn:

```
name A,
2,
name B,
name C,
3
name D,
name E,
...
```

and so on.

From the table I must create a linked list of objects `Expression(String, int, String)`,
for example:

```
Expression a = new Expression("name A", 2, "name B")
```

How could I extract the data from matrix in the right way to do this?

Comment: Next time why not try to solve it first and post your attempt rather than just throw your hands up and beg for a solution here.

Comment: I have tried to solve with no success obviously. Stackoverflow is for help in coding problems so... why this polemic?? -_-"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
String[][] matrix = { 
        { "name", "2", "name" }, 
        { "name", "2", "name" },
        { "name", "2", "name" }, 
        { "name", "2", "name" }, 
};

List<Expression> list=new LinkedList<Expression>();
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) 
    list.add(new Expression(matrix[i][0], Integer.parseInt(matrix[i][1]), matrix[i][2]));
```